# How to ask about material to study aviation related topics?

Tags: discussion

Since reading Aviation SE I noticed that I have a huge interest in everything related to aerodynamics so I'd like to know the whole topic in more depth. This led me to nearly asking about what the best materials available are for studying aerodynamics / aircraft physics coming from being a pilot, but that would be off topic / opinion based / too broad - rightfully so!

On the other hand, I still think, it could be good for Aviation.SE to have something similar like that listed somewhere, either as wiki article or whatever.

What is a good way of asking this question? I would ask it in the chat but I a) experienced in most SE network sites that the chat gets way less exposure than a question and b) the answer is something that is also interesting for others in a longer term.

Comment: Regarding your actual question: plenty of universities offer aerodynamics courses. Perhaps online lecture slides / textbooks referenced is a way to start?

Answer (score 1):

I think that jumping in chat would be better.

As you rightly pointed out, this type of question would be closed. Not only on this site, but plenty of others as well. Imagine if someone ask "*What are the best materials for learning C++?*", "*What are the best books for organic chemistry?*", "*Where can I learn vector calculus?*".

There is a huge amount of material on these topics in a variety of mediums, languages and depth. Perhaps StackExchange is not good for resource location at its current design.